# How to merge SQL SELECT fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I had a MySQL Table with an ENUM. Since I had to change this ENUM sometimes, I transfered it to another table. Now I have to create a statement, which will give me the name of the enum/newTable in one select field.

Table 1 (bottle):

```
id    | size      | size_id
1     | small     | (NULL)
2     | medium    | (NULL)
3     | big       | (NULL)
4     | (NULL)    | 1
5     | (NULL)    | 2
6     | (NULL)    | 3
```

Table 2 (bottle_size):

```
id    | name
1     | small
2     | medium
3     | big
```

SELECT:

```
SELECT id, <dontknow> as size
FROM bottle b
LEFT JOIN bottle_size bz ON b.size_id = bz.id
WHERE size = 'small';
```

How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of normalization of databases?

Comment: Half of your data uses text values, and the other half joins to a new `bottle_size` table? You might want to fix that first, get a level playing field.

Comment: sure i am... this is only an example for a much bigger database with thousands of rows in each table.. i cant change the layout, so i have to deal with it. @Mr Fuzzy Button: it is not text, it is an enum.. and like i've said before: the enum was to inflexible, so we had to transfer it.

Comment: You could run an UPDATE to join all the rows correctly, then leave the `bottle.size` text field unused?

Comment: yes i could, but thats not my decision... i can't change the layout and datasets, i only need a right select.

Comment: We have also different services, which write to that table and are still working with the enum. Some are not. So while the migration process isn't finished we couldn't be sure, that only one column is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to select either the first field if it is not `NULL` or the second field otherwise. Because this results in a dynamic field ("size"), you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` to add a condition:

```
SELECT b.id, IFNULL(b.size, bz.name) AS size
FROM bottle b
LEFT JOIN bottle_size bz ON b.size_id = bz.id
HAVING size = 'small';
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e2df/3

Answer (score 0):

Also available as a subquery :)

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  ifnull(b.size,
    (SELECT name FROM bottle_size bz WHERE bz.id=b.size_id)
        ) AS size_
FROM bottle b
HAVING size_ = 'small'
```

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e2df/15)